# Topos Theory as a link between logic and geometry

Tags: geometry, logic, category-theory, topos-theory

I was reading about topos theory and in many ways some people said that TT can be used to unify logic and geometry. What does that mean?

I have an OK background in category theory (at least up to adjunction theorems) and topology (general, differential and a little bit of algebraic topology) so feel free to those concepts in your explanation.

Comment: In typos theory, there is a way to give “forcing proofs” that use a kind of topology on the topos. So you can create proofs like Cohen’s forcing proofs in topos theory, and it follows the pattern of creating sheaves in geometry.

Comment: There is a good book, “Sheaves in Gometry and Logic: An Introduction to Topos Theory” by Mac Lane and Moerdijk which starts from the basics, so it feels fairly complete. Topos theory also models intuitionist logic - you can have non-Boolean topos, and, again using a kind of “sheaf,” from non-Boolean topos can construct a Boolean topos.

Comment: Of course, “typos” is a typo for topos. Really, an autocorrect failure.

Comment: The word "unify" is a little exagerated, "bridge" or "relate" would be more accurate. A good sign that indeed topos theory does make a convincing connexion is that topos were invented for their geometric/topologic content, but were rediscovered later by logicians for completely different motivations.

Comment: @CaptainLama Were they really "rediscovered" by logicians? I thought that Lawvere's definition of "elementary topos" was intended to be a generalization of the notion of "Grothendieck topos" from the start.

Comment: @AlexKruckman What I understood was that he became aware of Grothendieck topos when searching for logical frameworks, and then defined elementary topos as the more natural definition from the logical point of view, since the limitation of Grothendieck topos are not really relevant there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In topos theory, there is a way to give [forcing proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)) that use kinds of topologies and sheaves on the topos. So you can create proofs like Cohen’s forcing proofs in topos theory, and it follows the pattern of creating sheaves in geometry.

There is a good book, “[Sheaves in Geometry and Logic: A First Introduction to Topos Theory](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387977102)” by Mac Lane and Moerdijk which starts from the basics, so it feels fairly complete.

Topos theory also models intuitionist logic - you can have an intuitionist non-Boolean topos, and, again using a kind of “sheaf,” form a Boolean topos, so that the Boolean topos is sort of a quotient.

Comment: I guess that a book called "Sheaves in *Gometry*" would be a good introduction to "typos theory"...